# utf8 equivalent not displaying correct

Tags: c++

I am using the following code

```
int main()
{
    std::string str="\xc2b1";
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Now according to [this](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) c2b1 is equivalent to PLUS-MINUS SIGN
However when I run this code on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) I get the symbol

```
�
```

Is this an issue with the compiler ? Or am I doing something wrong I was expecting the symbol

```
±
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you not see the warning "hex escape sequence out of range"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\xc2b1` is asking to the compiler for a byte of value 0xc2b1, which isn't possible on pretty much any "normal" platform with 8-bit bytes.

What the site you linked is trying to say is that the *code point* (≈character) U+00B1 is expressed as a *sequence* of *two* UTF-8 code units (=bytes), specifically C2 B1. So, you have to write the two bytes as two separate escape sequences, i.e. `"\xc2\xb1"`.